# Migrating .NET 2.0 app from Win2003/IIS6 to Win2008/IIS7 - Performance issues

Tags: iis, performance

We are migrating our .Net 2.0 app from a physical Windows 2003 server with IIS 6 to a virtual Windows 2008 server with IIS 7 (classic). We see that the application is very slow, and most of the time, pages just throw an `IIS` issue.

We were able to narrow down that the pages that connect to our MSSQL Server 2005 database are causing the problem. If it is a very simple database pull, pages will come after some time. But pages that have a lot of database pulls just hang for a while and throw an `IIS` error.

Our application server is able to connect to the database server (which is on a different subnet), but it is extremely slow.

However, we are able to connect to the same db server from our old Windows 2003 server.

This issue has been killing us for more than 3 days.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What platform is the VM running on?  What's the connectivity look like to the database server - is it on the same network, or in a different location; are the latency and throughput reasonably equivalent to the old server?

Comment: VM runs on Win 2008 R2. DB server and the app server are under different subnets --> thats the only difference. Yes, latency is fine.